# Coordinates of two parallel lines knowing their distance

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to draw parallel lines knowing the distance between them. The lines are finite, I know the (x, y) coordinates of their origin and ending points, so I need to calculate, somehow, the (x, y) coordinates of both points of said parallel line.

Because english is not my first language I have made a diagram so you can understand better.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5yl8.jpg

I have added the coordinate system just in case I have there is some special case we need to worry about. Keep in mind that the line in the picture is just an example, I have to draw lines in any angle and orientation.

Any help is apreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: There are two parallel lines that fit this description.

Comment: I want the line that is displaced to the right in the direction of the original one, considering (x1, y1) as origin point and (x2, y2) as ending point. And I can't use slope calculations because that leads to division by zero in some scenarios.

Comment: It’s evident from your answer and comments that what you really wanted to find out and accomplish wasn’t what you asked. It would’ve been useful to know, for instance, that speed was more important to you than precision. If you’d like useful answer in the future, please include more context in your questions—GIGO.

Answer (score 2):

Let $w_1 = (x1, y1)$ and $w_2 = (x2, y2)$.  Then compute $d = w_2-w_1$.  Normalize it as follows $d_n = \frac{d}{\|d\|}$.  Now rotate $d_n$ by 90 degrees as

$$(e_x, e_y) = (-{d_n}_y, {d_n}_x)$$

Then, you can directly compute

$$(u1, v1) = v1 + 5(e_x,e_y)$$

and do the same for $(u2, v2)$.

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't get how to get the two points I need. I apologize if my basic math is a bit rusty.

Comment: What language are you coding in?

Comment: This is part of a personal project and it's all done in Java. I have made a comment on the original post explaining a bit more. Thanks a lot.

Comment: From the comment to the question, it looks like the OP wants to displace to the right, so I believe that he needs $(d_{ny},-d_{nx})$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 facts:

1-  The line $u_1,v_1$ to $x_1,y_1$is perpendicular to the original line, (and similarly the other end) so product of shores $-1$.

2- the distance of $u_1,v_1$ to $x_1,y_1$ is $5$ pixels

Comment: Thank you, tho not enough information I'm affraid.

Comment: @Benuva Can you explain what more information I am to add?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer myself even though I am sure both of your answers are probably correct. The fact that I cannot use slope due to division by zero when X or Y coordinates are the same made it a bit harder.

The following is a Java snippet and it is working perfectly right now:

```
// Calculate horizontal and vertical delta
double deltaX = x1 - x2;
double deltaY = y1 - y2;

// Used later to fix the side of displacement
int signX = (int) Math.signum( deltaX );
int signY = (int) Math.signum( deltaY );

// Origin point coordinates
float u1 = x1 + ( d * signY );
float v1 = y1 - ( d * signX );

// Destination point coordinates
float u2 = x2 + ( d * signY );
float v2 = y2 - ( d * signX );
```

The result is the points (u1, v1) and (u2, v2) I needed.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Unless the original line is horizontal or vertical, this will displace the endpoints along a direction that’s 45° to the coordinate axes instead of in a direction perpendicular to the line. The result will certainly be a parallel line (segment), but the distance between it and the original line will be $\sqrt2d$, not $d$. If that’s indeed what you wanted, that’s not at all what your question asked for.

Comment: Yes you are correct, but in my case the units of $d$ are irrelevant and I decided to reduce computational complexity by removing unnecessary calls to Math.sqrt() since this function is called many times. My apologies.

Comment: In other words, you don’t actually care about the distance between the lines? Why bother to multiply by $d$ at all, then?

Comment: Because I care about both lines being separated by some degree. What I don't care about is what units that separation is measured in. Thank you.

Comment: You’re welcome. If “the units ... are irrelevant,” then $1$ is as good a displacement as any. There is obviously some underlying unit that *isn’t* irrelevant—pixels, perhaps—but you didn’t make that clear in your question.

Comment: It’s evident from your answer and comments that what you really wanted to find out and accomplish wasn’t what you asked. It would’ve been useful to know, for instance, that speed was more important than precision. If you’d like useful answer in the future, please include more context in your questions—GIGO.